# problem about integral of arctan x

Tags: integration, derivatives, substitution

Hi i have one math question that i am struggling on.

which was just simple integral question range from 0 to 24
[image]

and so i applied **integral of arctan x property** here as above(Blue).

but answer is the 124.102 which is about 5times of my answer.

i guess i made mistakes substituting x/5 into integral property.

But this seems correct way to substitute. Hope somebody help me out for this.

Comment: You're misusing the chain rule. If $\int f(x)dx=F(x)+C$ then $\int f(x/a)dx=aF(x/a)+C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{24} 5 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right) d x=&\left[5 x \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\right]_0^{24} - 5 \int_0^{24} \frac{x}{1+\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{5} d x \\
= & 120 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)-25 \int_0^{24} \frac{x}{25+x^2} d x \\
= & 120 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)-\frac{25}{2}\left[\ln \left(25+x^2\right)\right]_0^{24} \\
= & 120 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)-\frac{25}{2} \ln \left(\frac{576}{25}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: May I have the opinions from the down-voter to improve my answer?